# number of query values and destination fields are not the same access

Tags: database, ms-access

When I run this command on my table, it is bringing back the error shown in the title, can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table2(VolsID, FirstName, LastName)" & _
"VALUES('" & Me.frst_Name_txt & "," & Me.lst_Name_txt & "," & _
Me.vol_ID_txt & "," & "')"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This. If VolsID is a string field, then wrap it with single quote. e.g. ('" & Me.frst_Name_txt & "')

```
 CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table2(VolsID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (" & Me.vol_ID_txt & ",'" & Me.frst_Name_txt & "','" & Me.lst_Name_txt & "');"
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I am getting a syntax erro when I run it however?

Comment: It is saying end of statement?

Comment: I am using 2013 version

Comment: the first name and last name = string fields, the VolsID = number field

Comment: Normally direct SQL statements ends with semicolon (;) for ms-access. let me check

Comment: Ok thanks, if you could show me hwo to get it working with just the first and last name; I can work it from there, first time doing insert. Got it so that I can insert into one field, but then not two or more

Comment: above SQL modified with semicolon. try now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table2(VolsID, FirstName, LastName)" & "VALUES('" & Me.frst_Name_txt & "','" & Me.lst_Name_txt & "','" & Me.vol_ID_txt & "')"
```