# error '3075' Syntax error (missing operator) access 2013

Tags: database, ms-access

The above error is being thrown when I run the below command:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table2(FirstName, LastName)" & "VALUES('" & Me.frst_Name_txt & ", '" & Me.lst_Name_txt & "','" & "')"
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Thanks

The error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have extra value `'" & "'` and also Text data types require delimiters around the value. At its simplest an apostrophe.

Try this

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table2(FirstName, LastName)" & "VALUES('" & Me.frst_Name_txt & "','" & Me.lst_Name_txt & "')"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it is still throwing the same error unfortunately

Comment: It is the same error as in the title of this question, it will be a mis-placed parantesis probably

Comment: I have included an image of the error in the question

Comment: @user2799788 I have updated answwer.. Can you check now

Comment: ahha! Success, thankyou for answering this question +1 my friend! Could you just do me one more answer, how would this look syntactically if I was inserting data into three fields?

Comment: @user2799788 I have added answer for your another question here.please check it http://stackoverflow.com/a/23309810/2118383

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an apostrophe: 
`CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table2(FirstName, LastName) VALUES('" & Me.frst_Name_txt & "', '" & Me.lst_Name_txt & "')"`